# Altium doesn't show traces when interactively routing

Tags: pcb-design, altium

When I try interactive routing, the traces don't show up until after I leave the interactive routing state. I've tried resetting desktop layouts, and showing all connections, but nothing I've seen works.

I'm running altium 13.3 in windows 7 in virtualbox (base os is Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Have you tried running Altium in virtual box before? It might be the virtualbox which makes it not work correct.

Comment: @Triak I haven't run altium in virtualbox before. it's possible the virtualization is affecting it, but I'd like to know why, especially because I feel like once the cause is know, there's a good chance it can be fixed. As I'm looking into things, it looks like directx isn't being rendered correctly, so I'm going to pursue that line.

Comment: Maybe try wine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Please, Check this preferences.

Comment: So alpha blending is "buggy / not supported" in Virtual Box?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using Altium 16 on VMware Workstation) Kübra answer won't work for me, but in the same page I found another solution.

Go to **Tools>Preferences>Display** and then disable **Apply Mask During Interactive Editing** as shown bellow.

[image]

- **EDIT**: There is an option in **View>Decrease Mask Level**, with "[" and "]" shortcut button. After using these commands I can adjust my mask level which is why I see all darks in interactive routing mode.